# I am missing something here? NetBeans is saying that it's expecting a "(" or "["

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public void getComputerPlayerTurn(String pid, ScopaCard card) {
    //checkPlayerTurn(pid);
    getPlayerHand(pid);
    int tempInt = playerHand.size();
    ArrayList<Rank> tempRanks = new ArrayList<Rank>           
        
    for (int i = 0; i < tempInt; i++) {
        card = playerHand.get(i).get(i);
        tempRanks.add(card.getRank());
    }
}
```

That's my code for a method that I'm trying to create. The aim of this for loop is to get the cards in a players hand, and add their ranks to a different ArrayList. Everything is fine apart from the  top line of the for loop (the one that has `for (int i = 0; ...)`). Here it is saying that a ( or [ is expected. I have no idea where though.
Cheers.

Comment: `ArrayList<Rank> tempRanks = new ArrayList<Rank> ` you're missing `();` at the end of this line

Comment: And although the error message was a bit cryptic, it was correct: either `(` (to start a constructor parameter list) or a `[` (to start an array dimension specification) would have been grammatically correct at this point. Note for the future: check the line *before* the error message for these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Rank> tempRanks = new ArrayList<Rank>
```

You forgot to put the constructor's brackets on the ArrayList. It should look like this:

```
List tempRanks = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Please accept one of the answers (click the green checkmark) to mark the question as [SOLVED]

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing the `()` at the end of array list declaration:

Syntax to declare array list ->

```
List<Rank> tempRanks = new ArrayList<Rank>();
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now

Comment: Its my pleasure.